# Can you identify this iPad music app

Tags: software

Can someone identify this iPad app?

[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not an appropriate question for this site.

Comment: Sorry Arch41, but identifying equipment such as the software used in this image is not [on-topic](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.